# Where is the bin directory in facebook-android-sdk-3.15.0

Tags: android, facebook

I am following this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started but in step 2."Install the Facebook SDK for Android and the Facebook APK" I cannot find the bin folder. Where is it?

Thanks in advance, I was searching here and in Google but couldn't find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bin folder was moved out of the SDK. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-3.x/

You can get it on the downloads page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/

Or directly from here https://developers.facebook.com/resources/Facebook-10.zip